# oracle sql query to get data from two tables of similar type

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I have two tables ACTUAL AND ESTIMATE having unique column(sal_id, gal_id, amount, tax).

In ACTUAL table I have
actual_id, sal_id, gal_id, process_flag, amount, tax
1 111 222 N  100 1
2 110 223 N  200 2

In ESTIMATE table I have
estimate_id, sal_id, gal_id, process_flag, amount, tax
3 111 222 N  50 1
4 123 250 N 150 2 
5 212 312 Y 10  1

Now I want a final table, which should have record from ACTUAL table and if no record exist for sal_id+gal_id mapping in ACTUAL but exist in ESTIMATE, then populate estimate record (along with addition of amount and tax).

In FINAL table
id  sal_id, gal_id, actual_id, estimate_id, total
**1 111     222       *1  null* 101** (since record exist in actual table for 111 222)
**2 110     223     *2   null* 202** (since record exist in actual table for 110 223)
**3 123     250      *null  4* 51** (since record not exist in actual table but estimate exist for 123 250)

(for 212 312 combination in estimate, since record already processed, no need to process again).

I am using Oracle 11g. Please help me on writing a logic in a single sql query?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the relationship between the tables ?

Comment: sal_id, gal_id is common for both table. I need to process the record based on ACTUAL / ESTIMATE table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to write this query.  One way is to use join and coalesce:

```
select coalesce(a.sal_id, e.sal_id) as sal_id,
       coalesce(a.gal_id, e.gal_id) as gal_id,
       coalesce(a.actual_value, e.estimate_value) as actual_value
from actual a full outer join
     estimate e
     on a.sal_id = e.sal_id and
        a.gal_id = e.gal_id
```

This assumes that sal_id/gal_id provides a unique match between the tables.

Since you are using Oracle, here is perhaps a clearer way of doing it:

```
select sal_id, gal_id, actual_value
from (select *,
             max(isactual) over (partition by sal_id, gal_id) as hasactual
      from ((select 1 as isactual, *
             from actual
            ) union all
            (select 0 as isactual, *
             from estimate
            )
           ) t
     ) t
where isactual = 1 or hasactual = 0
```

This query uses a window function to determine whether there is an actual record with the matching sal_id/gal_id.  The logic is to take all actuals and then all records that have no match in the actuals.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I modified my question little bit as need to populate actual_id/estimate_id in FINAL table.

Comment: Either version should work.  I like the second version better.